# What are the use cases for jQuery Templates in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, jquery-templates

For awhile now I have been looking for an overall data/markup strategy to settle into ASP.NET MVC, and am now currently looking at [jQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/).

jQuery templates appear to me to be a new binding system, similar to the MVC view engine or its various flavors, except that it does the data binding in the browser instead of the web server.  Am I essentially correct in this assessment?

When would you use jQuery templates instead of an ASP.NET MVC view template?  Is it to avoid multiple post-backs to the server while the user edits data, and if so, doesn't that essentially amount to pushing the functional equivalent of an old-style ADO.NET dataset (in JSON form) to the browser, and then posting it back to the web server when the user is done editing it?

What would some of the use cases for this sort of thing be?  An invoice form, perhaps? Under what conditions is it better for the data binding take place in the browser instead of on the web server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak to ASP.NET MVC patterns but in general jQuery templates (and any javascript templates) serve the purpose of applying views to data fetched via AJAX. Your typical template system will aid in rendering the page, but after the page is rendered and you make an AJAX request to post a new comment, and you want to add the comment into the page without loading it again, what would you do? Would you just return the entire HTML block? That's possible but it bloats the bandwidth of the requests when you could simply return a JSON object instead - which allows you to use the same request on multiple platforms and not just pigeonhole it to a Web page. With Javascript-based templates (even something like Mustache js) you can apply a template to a dataset (JSON response) directly in javascript so you can load your templates with the page load and use them whenever states change or new objects are introduced.

At the end of the day it's up to you to decide what you want to do. If you are using a common set of Services then you will probably have to apply templates in Javascript so your data requests do not have to return HTML themselves. But it is certainly possible to do so if you are only working with a regular website and not a service-based one. Keep in mind, though, that if you ever move to a service-based architecture all of your calls will have to be re-written then to avoid returning HTML so it's worth the consideration now.